# How to load database from disc to in-memory for ORACLE 12c

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, in-memory-database

I am new to oracle 12c and trying to measure the query time for the two cases,

1. Disc based database
2. In-memory database

   How can I know that the database I am currently accessing is on disc or in in-memory?
   How to enable the in-memory option so that I can load the data into memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Check the value of the initialization parameter `inmemory_size`.

```
SQL>show parameter inmemory_size
```

2) Set the value of `inmemory_size`.

```
SQL>ALTER SYSTEM SET inmemory_size = 20G scope=spfile;
```

You may need to increate SGA size as well since IM column store takes memory from it.

3) Alter table to load into memory

```
SQL>ALTER TABLE hr.emp INMEMORY;
```

[Getting started with Oracle Database In-Memory](https://blogs.oracle.com/In-Memory/entry/getting_started_with_oracle_database)